# MouseEvent.clientX and MouseEvent.clientY Unexpected Results With CSS Scale Transform

Tags: javascript, css, coordinates, mouse

```js
$('body').on('mousemove', function (ev) {
    $('span').text(`x: ${ev.clientX}, y: ${ev.clientY}`)
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div"></div>
<span id="my-span"></span>
```

I was just wondering why the scaled div returns x and y MouseEvent coordinates in the range from 0 to 150 instead of from 0 to 200?  The scale property is set to 2, so I thought it would be the second range instead of the first.  Could someone explain?  Here's a link to the [js fiddle page](https://jsfiddle.net/xs481ypf/).

I noticed a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow, so this might be a duplicate.  However, I couldn't find anything that specifically asked this question about pixels, coordinates, and the scale transformation in CSS.  I may have missed something, though...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `transform-origin` is center by default so half the div is outside the screen from the top/left.

Either update the transform-origin:

```js
$('body').on('mousemove', function (ev) {
    $('span').text(`x: ${ev.clientX}, y: ${ev.clientY}`)
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
  transform-origin:0 0;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div"></div>
<span id="my-span"></span>
```

Or add some margin:

```js
$('body').on('mousemove', function (ev) {
    $('span').text(`x: ${ev.clientX}, y: ${ev.clientY}`)
})
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
  margin:50px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my-div"></div>
<span id="my-span"></span>
```

Comment: have been watching this question to understand why OP had this problem. Learned today that `transform-origin` is center by default

Answer (score 1):

The div is scaled relative to its center, so part of it ends up being off screen. (One way to notice this: add a border to the div and see that it doesn't go all the way around.)

Try using `transform-origin: top left;` on the div - I think that will do what you expect.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was staring at that for over an hour:)